# Maximum Write Block Size for Aerospike

Tags: aerospike

According to the official Aerospike documentation- there is an upper limit on write block size: (https://docs.aerospike.com/display/AS2/Config+Parameters+Reference). Is it only for the persistent storage or does it also apply to the SSD-based storage?

Comment: I work at Aerospike and I am curious where you found this link from. This is a very old link and a lot has changed since. This is the latest link: http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/

Comment: Well I stumbled across it with good ol' google search. Just a suggestion- now that Aerospike has grown considerably- I think it would help the users a lot if you could have version specific documentation (like django for eg.!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it applies to SSD based storage, whether it's the primary storage engine, or if you're using a device to persist data-in-memory.

Comment: Thanks for the response! really appreciate it!